# Android studio gives error on compilation, No resource found

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I tried to compile a project with target SDK 13, and then i got few errors about resources. I got few same errors, and one of them is:

```
android-apt-compiler: [android-master5] C:\Documents and Settings\...\Local Settings\Application Data\Android\android-studio\sdk\android-master5\res\values\styles.xml:24: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar'.
```

What should I do ?

Sorry for bad english.

Comment: is this on 32-bit linux?

Answer (score 0):

In the file styles.xml that is mentioned in the error, if line 24 literally says:

```
'style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar'
```

then change it to:

```
'@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar'
```

(You just missed the @ symbol)

Comment: still the same problem, even if I type @ symbol

Comment: That's odd...Would you mind posting the contents of your styles.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

I found this post while searching for a similar error message that I got when migrating from eclipse to Android Studio. In my case the very same theme was not found for AndroidManifest.xml:

My Problem was solved by adding

```
compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
```

to the dependencies in the gradle file as suggested here:
https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock-Gradle-Sample

Speaking of, it seems AppCompat is the new thing for backwards compatible ActionBars...